# Help me to install ppp server on Ubuntu 12.04 server

Tags: server, software-installation, ppp

I want build `ppp` server on Ubuntu 12.04 Server.  I failed even after tried to 
install `ppp` server numerous times. I want to build ppp server like the below environment.

```
ppp client: Modem -------> NAS Network Access Sever--------------------> inthernet(ISP)
(embedded Target).........(PPP Server:ubuntu 12.04 installed vmware)
```

embedded Target was installed `ppp` client, so I am concerned about ppp server on Ubuntu.

I installed `pptpd`, `ppp`, `mgetty`, `openssl`  packages and I set configurations up according to [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2021763). However, it's not working.

Debugging info is

```
Dial start : ATDT9,750****
form modem : ATDT9,750****
route: SIOCDELRT: No such process
PPP START : /root/daehap/ppp/ppp-on ATDT9,750**** 00005@****.***.** 1234 115200&

::::: TIME END   -Dial : 700

CONNECT 28800 28800    
PROTOCOL:V42bis    
Debian GNU/Linux ttyS1 38400 (38400)    
**EMSI_REQA77E^Q    
ubuntu login: 00005@****.***.**    
Password:

Serial connection established.    
using channel 7    
Using interface ppp0    
Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyS1    
Warning - secret file /etc/ppp/pap-secrets has world and/or group 
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 asyncmap 0x0> magic 0x54e5c85e> pcomp> accomp>]    
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 asyncmap 0x0> magic 0x54e5c85e> pcomp> accomp>]    
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 asyncmap 0x0> magic 0x54e5c85e> pcomp> accomp>]    
sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 magic 0x1a78e02e>]    
rcvd [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 magic 0x1a78e02e>]    
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 asyncmap 0x0> magic 0x64a91fc7> pcomp> accomp>]    
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 asyncmap 0x0> magic 0x64a91fc7> pcomp> accomp>]    
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 asyncmap 0x0> magic 0x64a91fc7> pcomp> accomp>]    
sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 asyncmap 0x0> magic 0x64a91fc7> pcomp> accomp>]    
rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 asyncmap 0x0> magic 0x64a91fc7> pcomp> accomp>]    
sent [LCP ConfNak id=0x2 magic 0xf0e6bde2>]    
rcvd [LCP ConfNak id=0x2 magic 0xf0e6bde2>]    
.
.
.
```

I think `ppp` server didn't communicate LCP Protocol.

What do I do to make it work? Please give me idea.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should change the access settings for your /etc/ppp/pap-secrets file

> Warning - secret file /etc/ppp/pap-secrets has world and/or group

Second, there seems to be a Configuration Problem. You have multiple LCP ConfNak (LCP Configuration not Acknowledged) Packets, some are ok, but you need at least one LCP ConfAck(LCP Configuration Acknowledgement)

Answer (score -2):

Read this [doc](http://www.linuxdoc.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/ppp-server.html) from **linuxdoc** it will help you

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you provide detail on the link here please. See our [FAQ](http://askubuntu.com/faq). Thanks!